# Python: fernet key error / NameError: name 'fernet' not defined

Tags: python, redis, cryptography, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to deploy the bot’s discord, `discord.py / python` ([link to git](https://github.com/Xenon-Bot/xenon-main/tree/premium)) on the service `heroku` (
[link](https://heroku.com)).

**The following error appears during deployment:**

```
app [worker.1]: trace (last call was last):
app [worker.1]: file "run.py", line 9, in <module>
app [worker.1]: redis_url = env.get ("REDIS_URL") or "redis: // localhost /"
app [worker.1]: file "/app/bot.py", line 15, in __init__
app [worker.1]: self._fernet_key = fernet.Fernet (env ["FERNET_KEY"]. encode ("utf-8"))
app [worker.1]: NameError: name 'fernet' not defined
```

> Is this error due to the `fernet key`? If so, how
>   specify the specified key correctly.
>
> Is this error due to an incorrectly specified `redis url`? If yes, then
>   how to properly conduct it.
>
> If the problem is still something, please indicate this.

*UPDATE:*

Added to `requirements.txt` of the main repository:
`cryptography == 2.9.2`
`fernet == 1.0.1`

**The following error appeared:**

```
app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[worker.1]:   File "run.py", line 9, in <module>
app[worker.1]:     redis_url=env.get("REDIS_URL") or "redis://localhost/"
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/bot.py", line 16, in __init__
app[worker.1]:     self._fernet_key = fernet.Fernet(env["FERNET_KEY"].encode("utf-8"))
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 35, in __init__
app[worker.1]:     key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(key)
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/base64.py", line 133, in urlsafe_b64decode
app[worker.1]:     return b64decode(s)
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
app[worker.1]:     return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
app[worker.1]: binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Comment: Check your `requirements.txt`. Do you have `fernet` listed in there? If not, then add it, as it seems to be a package that your bot depends on.

Comment: If you do have it, make sure you've imported it too in your script

Comment: @Diggy. This module is not in the original requirement of the author, but I installed it through `pip install`, the error continue

Comment: If your module uses it, then you should add it into the `requirements.txt` anyway

Comment: @Diggy.  Did as you wrote. A new error has appeared. Added her code to the top start.